# ArrayAdapter alternative

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I'm finding a displaying problem in my app and one of the users advices me to not use ArrayAdapter... i'm wondering if i can't use other thing...
here is my function that i have to use an ArrayAdapter on it:

```
public void updatelv(Activity activity) {
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        String fileName = getResources().getString(R.string.fileName);
        fileDir = "" + preferences.getString("login", "") + "."+ preferences.getString("marque", "") + ".";
        s = myIO.ReadFilePerLine(getApplicationContext(), fileDir+fileName);
        ListView L = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        L.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, s[0]));
    }
```

And this is the data that i want to store whenever i tap on a button:

```
data = date + " : " + y + "L/100KM\n"+ " " + value1 + "L "+ value2 + "KM\n";
```

Thank you for your help :).

Comment: what problem are you experiencing when using an ArrayAdapter?

Comment: @Hakan: The display of datas are not well done! When i tap a button the ListView indicates that i have not any datas to display, if i tap another time, the datas (and the new one) are displayed + i organized the display of the variables(exp: variable a then b then c then d) sometimes i have: c then d then a then b ! anyway, i maked a video, please view it(http://www.4shared.com/video/Tdps8spN/problem.html). Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Hakan: so any response/comment ? :\

Comment: I suggest then you should write your own ListAdapter. It gives you more control/flexibility on your List. Android has used custom adapters before in their tutorials. If you want to see a sample, check out the GridView example here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html